# Date ranges in LUIS

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm using LUIS for recognising date ranges for a travel agent chatbot. All works for me, but for some reason, I can't get utterances without a date separator to work. For example "12 13 Sep" is not recognized as a date range, even though "12-13 Sep" is. I read somewhere that LUIS uses [chrono](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono) for date parsing, but "12 13 Sep" works perfectly on Chrono.

I'm in a fix because many of my users are being affected by this. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions you may want to try:

1. In your prompt specify the date format needed to properly recognize the date range. I'm assuming you prompt the user i.e. "what days would you like to travel" or "what are your travel dates" adding something like "please format you date as start day - end day month" or something similar may do the trick to help guide your users.
2. You may be able to create a composite entity like `{{startDate}{endDate}{month}}` or `{{startDate}{endDate}{startMonth}{endMonth}}`. This is kind of a hacky solution, but it might work for you.